# System.Web.HttpException / Converting code to proper MVC architecture

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-partialview, httpexception

My team have been working on building a comment section for a school project and render it in a partial view.

This is the solution that I came up with:

On Index page:

```
@Html.Partial("StatusWall", new Project.Services.StatusServices())
```

StatusWall:

```
@model Project.Services.StatusServices

@foreach (var status in Model.GetAllUserStatuses())
{...
```

Code in StatusService:

```
public List<UserStatus> GetAllUserStatuses()
    {
        //check
        var StatusResult = (from status in db.UserStatuses
                            orderby status.DateInserted descending
                            select status).ToList();
        return StatusResult;
    }
```

This works, but the problem is that we're not using a proper MVC architecture, since we're bypassing the controller. Since the design of our project requires that I use a partial view, I had no idea how to call the controller, until my assistant pointed out the [ChildActionOnly] attribute

Now, I'm trying to incorporate the code to a MVC model but the solution, so far, eludes me.

Here's what I've written in the Controller:

```
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult StatusWall() {
        var service = new StatusServices();
        var result = service.GetAllUserStatuses();
        return PartialView(result);
    }
```

Index page:

```
@Html.Action("StatusWall")
```

All other code is unchanged.

This tosses the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.

Can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized what was wrong.

I changed...

```
@model Project.Services.StatusServices

@foreach (var status in Model.GetAllUserStatuses())
{...
```

...into...

```
@model List<Project.Models.UserStatus>

@foreach (var status in Model)
{...
```

There was also some minor fixing, like turning ActionResult into PartialViewResult, but I don't know if that was necessary for the code to work.